# xorg-x11-server-common still needed?

Tags: x11, xorg, x

**xorg-x11-server-common**

> Internet services that are not required for system or application processes must not be active to decrease the attack surface of the system. *X Windows has a long history of security vulnerabilities* and will not be used unless approved and documented.

So there is this rule that claims X is bad.  It seems that if in CentOS7 (i.e. RHEL7) removing `xorg-x11-server-common` results in the following also being removed

```
xorg-x11-drv-fbdev
xorg-x11-drv-evdev
xorg-x11-drv-v4l
xorg-x11-drv-ati
xorg-x11-server-xorg
xorg-x11-drivers
xorg-x11-drv-intel
xorg-x11-drv-synaptics
xorg-x11-qxl
xorg-x11-vmware
xorg-x11-wacom
xorg-x11-void
xorg-x11-nouveau
xorg-x11-vmmouse
xorg-x11-ves
xorg-x11-dummy
```

In doing so after a reboot I no longer have a graphical login at the console, doing a `init 5` or `systemctl isolate graphical.target` results in an error, it's now like sitting at a commodore hooked up to the living room tv but black & white not black & green.

My question is, for a server in a work environment where users would not sit at a console but rather VNC or remote in over the network, will graphical programs like libreoffice, firefox, the graphical user manager in gnome `system-config-users` work?  Or does removing xorg bring us back to the 70's style of computing?  How ingrained is Xorg-x11-* would gnome and right-click new terminal still work?

**update:** so it appears it is very needed if you want to have any kind of windowing including your mouse and keyboard working.

- xorg-x11-drv-evdev = input driver for Linux's generic event devices, it therefore supports all input devices that the kernel knows about, including most mice and keyboards.
- can't install that or `xorg-x11-drivers` without having `xorg-x11-server-common` installed
- thanks for playing, I recovered  by doing `yum install x11-xorg-drivers` which basically reinstalls everything including *server-common*

Comment: Source of the quote??

Comment: https://vaulted.io/library/disa-stigs-srgs/RHEL_7_STIG/V-72307

Comment: https://github.com/RedHatGov/ssg-el7-kickstart/issues/69

Comment: would also like to know what `internet services` this rpm provides.